# How to record Audio on android(2.3) from pc?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

I have single board computer with android 2.3 (max version for my board). and audio input/output(3.5mm) interfaces.
  I need to stream audio from my PC in real time via audio interface (not USB, or WI-FI). First of all, it`s possible?

I have simple app, that using AudioRecorder  and AudioTrack classes.
And this app car record some data, but this data always are different.
Also, I got some data, when cable is disconnected.

Main part of app:

```
int sampleRate = 8000;
    int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    int minInternalBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
            channelConfig, audioFormat);
    int internalBufferSize = minInternalBufferSize * 4;
    Log.d(TAG, "minInternalBufferSize = " + minInternalBufferSize
            + ", internalBufferSize = " + internalBufferSize
            + ", myBufferSize = " + myBufferSize);

    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,
            sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, internalBufferSize);
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, internalBufferSize*4, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    Log.d(TAG, "init state = " + audioRecord.getState());
    Log.d(TAG, "record start");
    audioRecord.startRecording();
    track.play();
    int recordingState = audioRecord.getRecordingState();
    Log.d(TAG, "recordingState = " + recordingState);

    Log.d(TAG, "read start");
    isReading = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (audioRecord == null)
                return;

            byte[] myBuffer = new byte[myBufferSize];
            int readCount = 0;
            int totalCount = 0;
            int h = 0;
            while (isReading) {
                readCount = audioRecord.read(myBuffer, 0, myBufferSize);
                totalCount += readCount;
                myBuffer2 = myBuffer;
                track.write(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.length);


                Log.d(TAG, "readCount = " + readCount + ", totalCount = "+ totalCount);
                if (h<5){
                    for (int i=0;i<myBuffer.length;i+=100){
                        Log.d(TAG, "myBuffer index = " + i + ", value = "
                                + myBuffer[i] + " , iter = " + h);
                    }
                    h++;
                }


            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Board can work only with this audioRecorder config: 8000 - samplerate, mono_channel, encoding_pcm_16bit.

What data I recieved? I`m not sure, that is from my PC.

While `track.play();` I can hear some noise, that look likes some system noise.

Any help would be great.